# Accessing value of recordset

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that obtains a recordset of attributes from Active Directory.

I can access most of the returned values like this

```
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Debug.Print (rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value)
Debug.Print (rs.Fields("GivenName").Value)
```

However the returned value for `postOfficeBox` looks like it could be a variant.

[image]

How do I access the value? I tried

```
Debug.Print (rs.Fields("postOfficeBox").value(0))
```

That did not work - Run Time Error 450.

Comment: https://www.winvistatips.com/threads/unable-to-list-postofficebox-attribute.759934/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim Williams. I manage to get it to return a value like this:

```
Dim arrPOBox As Variant
Dim strPOBox As String
....
Set rs = cmd.Execute
arrPOBox = rs.Fields("postOfficeBox").Value
strPOBox = CStr(arrPOBox(0))
```